# Configure widgets on Sonar does not work

Tags: configuration, sonarqube

Whenever I try to click the "Configure widgets" button, SonarQube displays the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page. Everything else works fine.

Has anyone had the same problem and found a solution? Or should I reinstall?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem while using SonarQube 3.7.4 (LTS) on Windows. I solved it by using Oracle's JRE 7 instead of JRE 8.

When looking into the SonarQube documentation, it says that SonarQube analysis and SonarQube server require some specific versions of the JVM to be executed. Version 8 is only supported since SonarQube 4.3. (Source: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements)
The following page reports of the issue: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5191

To change the JVM which SonarQube uses, you can modify the wrapper.conf file in the conf folder of the sonar package. More specifically, change the line wrapper.java.command=java to point to the path on your machine where an version older than 8 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a message error in your log with more precisions about what did happen. Have you looked at it?

Regards.